# React + Firestore Reference an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, database, google-cloud-firestore

How do I reference an array in the collections? For example: I have a `collection("Info").doc("Username").collection()` in which the collection () contains a list of user hobbies in an array. How would i reference it and display it?

Answer (score 1):

You can get references to subcollection by

```
collection("Info").doc("Username").listCollections()
```

Reference: https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Firestore.html#listCollections